# How to make a Google Appengine task repeatable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This is for a homework assignment. Normally I would use cron to do something like this, but teacher wants us to create a task queue that polls a server for information on a regular interval.

So far I have something like this:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(
    withUrl("/MyPage").
    method(Method.GET).
    param("user", viewModel.getUserId()));
```

But this only runs once. How can I get it to repeat indefinitely?

Comment: @Gwyn Howell I said specifically that I am NOT using cron. I am asking how to make a queue repeat.

Comment: apologies. have you seen the deferred library? https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

Comment: I took a quick look. It appears to be a higher abstraction of the task queue, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the code that runs in the task add another task to the queue

Comment: Good idea, I think this is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with not a very graceful way. If your task fails with RuntimeException it will be restarted automatically. You can use config to manage how offen do you want it to be repeated. Check https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue for details. And it is important not use default queue, because you will need additional parameters.

It is not a natural way to schedule tasks, but it will work for you.

Comment: Hmm, so there is no non-hacky way to make a task repeat?

Comment: It is not a hacky way. But it is not a regular restart. It will be easy if you will use DefferedTask to throw Exception, but you can return HTTP code other than 200 for your "/MyPage"

Comment: Well I guess our definition of hacky is not the same ;) Throwing an exception when everything completed successfully does not seem like good practice to me.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to restart task itself with DeferredTask

deferSubmitTask() is called when finishing task

```
private static class DeferredSubmitTask implements DeferredTask
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            QueueFactory.getQueue("submitqueue").add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/tasks/submitworker").taskName("submit"));
        }
        catch (com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskAlreadyExistsException ex)
        {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "submit task launch failed, it is still running...");
        }
    }
}

public static void deferSubmitTask(long countdownMillis)
{
    QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(new DeferredSubmitTask()).countdownMillis(countdownMillis));
}
```